# Какую разметку использовать при создании проекта в Android Studio?

Tags: android

Вопрос относительно к профи.

Какую разметку использовать при создании проекта в Android Studio?

Я имею ввиду про макет. Когда вы создаете проект, в каком макете начинаете делать проект? тобишь стандартный макет?

Nexus 5? или Nesus S? или другой какой - то?

главное что это повлияло на будущее чтобы на разных устройствах нормально отображался проект.

P.S.
Думаю этот вопрос для новичков очень сильно заинтересует и много людей заглянет в этот топик

Comment: Вы можете ориентироваться на самые распространённые версии `API` и плотности экранов. Еженедельно обновляемая официальная статистика по этим параметрам есть тут: [Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/about/dashboards/index.html)

Comment: в данный момент в приоритете hdpi и xhdpi, тогда лучше делать в xhdpi? так как если в большой плотности будет в идеале значит и в меньшем тоже будет лучше, верно?

Comment: На счёт этого не знаю - вообще никогда об этом не задумывался) По мне так - если вёрстка не поехала, значит всё норм. А пиксели ловить - дело дизайнеров)

Comment: ясно. А вы вообщем когда пишете проект в какой разметке пишете и смотрите? Nexus какой?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду предпросмоторщик разметки, встроенный в студию или эмулятор/девайс?

Comment: Первое, предпросмотрщик

Comment: Его, предпросмоторщик, лучше вообще не использовать. Он аццки глючный, в нём куча нюансов и лично мне (как и многим другим) он, за годы разработки, ни разу не пригодился. Если тестировать - то только на девайсах/эмуляторах.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, незнаю что там у вас аццки глючит в студии, у меня всегда тот же дизайн что на устройстве, что в предпросмотрщике

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы все нормально отображалось на всех устройствах никогда не указывайте ширину или высоту View в пикселях для этого используйте dp

Comment: этого не достаточно, все равно можно разницу больную увидеть на разных устройствах. Вы видимо только на одном устройстве тестили, или только осваиваете андроид

Comment: нет просто вопрос был для новичка, а когда я начинал писать под андроид у меня были проблемы из-за пикселей, по этому такой совет и дал